# Nuget resources .dll generating with WIX in WPF app

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, nuget, wix

I have a WPF project which uses my nuget. This nuget implements localization, so it be able to be display resources in different languages, when i build my project which uses this nuget then the build folder contains the proper localization dll files for nuget package, but when i deploy the application with WIX, then after the installation the app's folder does not contain the proper nuget resources dll files.

How to solve this problem?

I would like to use my nuget with different string localization in the installed version as same as local version.

Comment: Haven't used WiX for a long time but isn't it that you define the structure for the installation folder there? Show us your WiX file and probably there's some mistake in it.

Comment: I found the solution, see the answer section https://stackoverflow.com/a/77051138/16455198

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already found a solution, when you use wix tool editor in Visual Studio, you can choose this toggle button (see the screenshot below), which display external resources which come from .dll files (exactly the nuget resources.dll file in this case), and you are able to add these files to your Product.wxs configuration.

link to image

Feel free to use this solution.

Comment: dont use image .

Comment: @sep7696 ok, but I need at least 10 reputation to post images.